# Can you add an action to an element within the tooltip in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a line chart drawn with chart.js that shows some data.
I've added a delete element within the tooltip, but I don't know if it's possible to add an interaction, so that when I click the delete element, within the tooltip, some custom code is run that deletes the data from the Data base.

```
const weight_graphOptions = {
  title: {
    text: 'Weight',
    display: true
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        // Luxon format string
        tooltipFormat: 'dd-MM-yyyy'
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Date'
      }
    },
    y: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'kg'
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      events: ['click'],
      callbacks: {
        afterFooter:
          function (addDeleteButton) {
            return 'Delete'
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know if I can do this without building my own custom-made tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible with the default provided tooltip, first it won't stay so when you try to hover the tooltip it's not there anymore
Second reason it won't work is because chart.js does not have any event listeners that listen to clicks/hovers over specific parts of the tooltip or the tooltip in general.

So you will need to make a custom [external](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips) html tooltip that stays even while you don't hover datapoint anymore where you can add a normal button

Comment: Thank you very much.
Do you know where I can find an example where an action is done on a specific tooltip element in chart.js?

Comment: Not as far as I know